# lua calculator not working properly

Tags: lua, calculator

when i type something else than + - * or / it still prints everything out only in the end it says "invalid"

```
print("+-*/?")
method = io.read()
if method == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/" then
  print("type a number")
  num1 = io.read()
  print("type another number")
  num2 = io.read()
elseif method ~= "+" or "-" or "*" or "/" then
  print("invalid")
end

if method == "+" then
  plusnum = num1 + num2
  print(plusnum)
elseif method == "-" then
  minusnum = num1 - num2
  print(minusnum)
elseif method == "*" then
  timesnum = num1 * num2
  print(timesnum)
elseif method == "/" then
  percentnum = num1 / num2
  print(percentnum)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the following line:

```
if method == "+" or "-" or "*" or "/" then
```

From [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual 3.4.5 Logical Operators](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.5)

> The logical operators in Lua are and, or, and not. Like the control
>   structures (see §3.3.4), all logical operators consider both **false and**
>   **nil as false** and **anything else as true**.

So no matter what method is, the condition of your if statement will always evaluate to `true` as you're `or`ing at least one `true` value which results in `true`.

As Egor already mentioned you have to use:

```
if method == "+" or method == "-" or method == "*" or method == "/" then
```